# Can't Parse localhost XML file (NullPointerException)

Tags: java, android, xml, wamp

I tried to make XML parser in android, the xml file is on my localhost server. I got NullPointerException error when I set the URL to my localhost-ed xml file, but when I upload the xml file to dropbox, my parser is working.

**the error message:**

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.StringReader.<init>(StringReader.java:47)
at com.learn.dhemas.franchise.XMLParser.getDomElement(XMLParser.java:74)
at com.learn.dhemas.franchise.fragmentLowongan$getDataOrder.doInBackground(fragmentLowongan.java:72)
...
```

**XMLParser,java:**

```
public class XMLParser {
    // constructor
    public XMLParser() {

    }

    /**
     * Getting XML from URL making HTTP request
     * @param url string
     * */
    public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
        String xml = null;

        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // return XML
        return xml;
    }

    /**
     * Getting XML DOM element
     * @param XML string
     * */
    public Document getDomElement(String xml){
        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is);

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        return doc;
    }

    /** Getting node value
     * @param elem element
     */
    public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
        Node child;
        if( elem != null){
            if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
                for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                    if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                        return child.getNodeValue();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

    /**
     * Getting node value
     * @param Element node
     * @param key string
     * */
    public String getValue(Element item, String str) {
        NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);
        return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
    }
}
```

**and lines of code from my activity (fragment class)**:

```
...
 @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //Call parser
        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        //String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B5bM7szIFKrpY2lPRHdCUUNscjA");
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl("http://localhost/GetData.xml");
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml);
...
```

Any help will be apreciated

Comment: replace localhost with the ip address of where your web server and file are

Comment: I've tried that, doesnt work either

Comment: Which server is? try http://localhost:8080/GetData.xml

Comment: android = one device localhost = another device.  Is localhost actually running a web server?

Comment: the server is running on my computer, and I use an emulator on the same computer to run the app. So how can I tell the android app to point the `localhost` on my localhost server instead of pointing it self?

Comment: **Update**
Problem solved by establishing a local network and give my computer an IP address. Thanks guys for helping me, I cant figure it on my own :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is when I point to localhost from the app then it will be the localhost on the emulator, instead of localhost in my web server. To solve this I just need to create a virtual local network and give my computer an IP address so I can access the IP from emulator.

Answer (score -2):

You can try to open the url : `http://localhost/GetData.xml` in the browser

Comment: yes, I can open `http://localhost/GetData.xml`.
Changing `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` doesnt work either, fyi I run that app on emulator

Comment: try browser in emulator @Dhemas .  (localhost || 127.0.0.1) == emulator. You may need change to other ip.

Comment: sorry for being confused xD
Now I get it, when I point to `localhost` from the app then it will be the `localhost` on the emulator, instead of `localhost` in my web server. Why so hard to figuring it my self lol. Thanks for your help